# get text value of selected dropdown menu option using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the text within the selected dropdown menu option using jQuery?

I have tried:

```
var title = $("#selectattribute option:selected").text();
```

But I don;t think it works..

Comment: @Robin - `.val()` returns the `value`, which is not the same as the text inside an option ==> `<option value="this">A choice</option>`

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did should work:

```
$("select option:selected").text()
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mq22e/)

Since it's not working for you, the error must lie somewhere else. Maybe `#selectattribute` is incorrect.

To clarify some of the other answers, the `value` of an option is different from the `text` inside it.

For example:

```
<select>
    <option value="red" selected="selected">Ferrari</option>
</select>

// For the above HTML
$("select option:selected").text() === 'Ferrari'
$("select option:selected").val()  === 'red'
```

Also, if no `selected` attribute is set in the HTML, the first `option` will be selected:

```
<select>
    <option value="black">Porsche</option>
    <option value="red"  >Ferrari</option>
</select>

// For the above HTML
$("select option:selected").text() === 'Porsche'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the select box by simply using:

```
var title = $("#selectattribute").val();
```

To get the text of the option, instead of the `value` attribute:

```
var title = $("#selectattribute :selected").text();
```